# Как сортировать по названию и потом только по числу .sort()

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка

[image: скрин скрипта]

Массив сортируется, но второй параметр ячейки массива (там где числа) сортируется не правильно. Была написала функция `compareNumeric`, но знаю что не правильно её использую.
В идеале массив должен сортировать по названию (первый параметр ячейки массива) и потом только по его `id` (второй параметр ячейки).

```js
var rows = [];
    for(var id = 3; id < 72; id++) {
        var customerID, contactType;
        for (var abc = 2; abc < 10; abc++) {
            if (abc == 6) {
                var thiscell = $('.rows:nth-child('+id+') li:nth-child('+abc+')');
                customerID = thiscell.attr('id').slice(9,thiscell.attr('id').length);
                contactType = thiscell.text();
            }
        }
        rows.push([contactType, customerID]);
    }
    function compareNumeric(a, b) {
        if (a > b) return 1;
        if (a < b) return -1;
    }
    rows.sort(compareNumeric);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправьте функцию сравнения, она получает два элемента массива, который нужно отсортировать. В вашем случае каждый элемент будет представлять собой массив из двух элементов, которые и сравнивайте по очереди, в нужном порядке.

```js
var rows = [
  ["Domestic", "14"],
  ["Bussiness", "10"],
  ["Domestic", "12"],
  ["Bussiness", "2"],
  ["Bussiness", "14"]
];

function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
  if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
  if (+a[1] > +b[1]) return 1;
  if (+a[1] < +b[1]) return -1;
  return 0;
}
rows.sort(compareNumeric);
console.log(rows);
```

В этом примере, допустил, что customerId должен сравниваться как число (для конвертирования в число стоят знаки `+`).

Comment: спасибо, работает)

Comment: ну тогда можно упростить  `function compareNumeric(a, b) {
     if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
     return +a[1] > +b[1];
   }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rows = [
  ["Domestic", "14"],
  ["Bussiness", "10"],
  ["Domestic", "12"],
  ["Bussiness", "2"],
  ["Bussiness", "14"]
];

var div = document.getElementById('output');

rows.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a[0] == b[0]) {
    return (+a[1] < +b[1]) ? -1 : (+a[1] > +b[1]) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  else {
    return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
});

for(x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
  div.innerHTML += rows[x][0] + ' ' + rows[x][1] + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```